# Remove links from Wordpress menu items with specific class

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to remove the entire `<a>` tag from a menu item with a specific class.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="whatever">Whatever</li>
  <li class="remove-link"><a href="whatever">Whatever</a></li>
  <li><a href="whatever">Whatever</li>
<ul>
```

Would generate

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="whatever">Whatever</li>
  <li class="remove-link"></li>
  <li><a href="whatever">Whatever</li>
</ul>
```

The code I am currently using removes the `<a>` tag but not based on the class:

```
function remove_links( $menu ) {
    return str_replace( '<a href="whatever">Whatever</a>', '', $menu );
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'remove_links' );
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the `<li></li>` tag or want it to be removed as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about WordPress but in pure JavaScript this can be done by this code -

Have a look

```js
...

document.querySelector(".remove-link").innerHTML = "";

...
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of using JS but it works. I'm going to leave this question open a bit longer cause I would like to see if someone comes up with a way to do this using PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Is it a dynamic menu? Is that pulled from the database or something?

Comment: Yes, it is a dynamic menu so I don't know what the value of the href or the text will be, only the class on the <li>

Comment: As I told you before I'm not into WordPress and didn't know how they work and also don't know what you want to do, but from my perspective, you can add an extra column that will indicate that this link should be disabled and if this menu is rendered through any loop, you can add if condition to filter out those disabled link.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it seems like this makes more sense to do in JS. But if you you want to do it with PHP with your existing function, it looks like you're only missing the li with the class there.

So change `return str_replace( '<a href="whatever">Whatever</a>', '', $menu );`

to `return str_replace( '<li class="remove-link"><a href="whatever">Whatever</a></li>', '<li class="remove-link"></li>', $menu );`

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't know what value the href will have or the text value.

Comment: The problem with your code is that ```<a href="whatever">Whatever</a>``` could have any href value or any text value; whatever is a dynamic value I used as a placeholder..

Answer (score 0):

The code will look like this:

```php
function cc_add_search_form( $items, $args ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location == 'menu_1' ) {
        $items_array     = explode( PHP_EOL, str_replace( "\r", '', $items ) );
        $new_items_array = array();
        foreach ( $items_array as $line ) {
            if ( preg_match( '/<li[^>]*class="[^"]*\bremove-link\b[^"]*"[^>]*>/i', $line ) ) {
                $new_items_array[] = preg_replace( '/(<a[^>]*>.*?<\/a>)/is', '', $line );
            } else {
                $new_items_array[] = $line;
            }
        }

        $items = trim( join( PHP_EOL, $new_items_array ) );
    }

    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'cc_add_search_form', 10, 2 );
```

Here you need to understand a few things:

- code using `$args->theme_location == 'menu_1'` check, so we don't destroy all the menus. we check the menu location and if matches then we do our job.
- we're making an array for loop from the given items by splitting the contenting from EOL = END OF LINE
- Then we loop and match the class in the `<li>` tag.
- If a match is a success then we replace the `<a>` tag and its content with an empty string using regex and store it in an array, if the match fails then we don't replace anything and store the line into an array.
- at last, we again JOIN the lines by EOL and return the updated items.